# Run time error 1004: Items missing in OLAP cube

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am using a nested for-loop in a macro to filter through my data and accordingly extract the data. The data is getting filtered for the first filter. But it throws a `1004 error : items not present in OLAP cube` when it goes on to execute my second/third/fourth filter.

I even tried rebuilding the data model and redefined the existing relationships. It's still not working.Can someone have a look at my code and let me know what's happening.

```
Sub EXTRACT_TOD_DATA()


  Dim CustRng As Range, RunnerRng As Range, CommodityRng As Range, 
  FactoryRng 
  As Range
  Dim cu As Range, r As Range, cm As Range, f As Range

  Sheets("tod").Activate


  Sheets("tod").PivotTables("PivotTable1").ClearAllFilters


  Set CustRng = Range("AE2:AG2")
  Set RunnerRng = Range("AE3:AG3")
  Set CommodityRng = Range("AE4:AF4")
  Set FactoryRng = Range("AE5:AF5")


  For Each cu In CustRng
      For Each r In RunnerRng
          For Each cm In CommodityRng
              For Each f In FactoryRng

                  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
                      "[Sales_ana].[Customer Name].[Customer Name]").CurrentPageName = _
                      "[Sales_ana].[Customer Name].&[" & cu.Value & "]"

                  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
                      "[Runner Levels].[Runner Level].[Runner Level]").CurrentPageName = _
                      "[Runner Levels].[Runner Level].&[" & r.Value & "]"

                  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
                      "[AGC_commodity].[Commodity].[Commodity]").CurrentPageName = _
                      "[AGC_commodity].[Commodity].&[" & cm.Value & "]"


                  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
                      "[Sales_ana].[Factory_Codes].[Factory_Codes]").CurrentPageName = _
                      "[Sales_ana].[Factory_Codes].&[" & f.Value & "]"

              Next f
          Next cm
      Next r
  Next cu


End Sub
```

Comment: For readability, you should work on indenting the code to general standards (e.g., for each on one line, then indent for what happens *during* that loop)

Comment: I did indent the sections properly now. Does it make sense to you? Do you see any evident bugs in the code? I'm a bit baffled as the code is working for the first filter, just not for the others.

Comment: Let's make sure we're looking at this appropriately, you intended to re-do the `"[Factory_Codes]".CurrentPageName` for every time you loop through items for cm, r, and cu?  Depending on your error, you might not have a found value or you have no visible data within the filter (the latter typically throws a mismatch error).

Comment: A note from the microsoft docs for `.CurrentPageName`: [Returns or sets the currently displayed page of the specified PivotTable report. The name of the page appears in the page field. Note that this property works only if the currently displayed page already exists.  This property applies to PivotTables that are connected to an OLAP data source. Attempting to return or set this property with a PivotTable that is not connected to an OLAP data source will result in a run-time error.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield.currentpagename).

Comment: Yes, it's a nested for loop where the customer filter is the largest level of filter. Once I filter based on customer, I go on changing the other filters and extract the data. The funny thing is that I used the same concept to filter 6 different categories a few weeks back and it worked. I don't know what's the issue now.

Comment: My guess is that you're filtering where there isn't an option, e.g., your sheet says `cu.value = "A"` & `r.value = "cat"`but your pivot table does not have a "cat" in [Runner Levels] after you've filtered [Sales_ana] for "A", so it throws an error as there is no filter available (at least 1 filtered value is required).

Comment: Is there a way to check if my pivot table is connected to an OLAP source? Because as mentioned in the comments, I rebuilt the data model and even redefined the relationships. Yet, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Use refresh in the... i think it's "layout" ribbon once you've selected any cell in the pivot table.  you might also want to re-assign the source data to be sure.

Comment: Cyril, its working now. Turns out the values in the data column had a trailing white space in the beginning, as a result of which the values were not getting filtered. LOL!! I spent the entire day trying to debug that. Well thank you for your comments. Appreciate the effort. :)